# critical meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> When I'm in a relationship, I can be critical of my partner.

What does the critical mean here? what's the meaning of this sentence? thank you

Comment: It means that the speaker finds faults in his or her romantic partners. He or she criticises them (not necessarily to their faces).

Comment: Ahh thank you, do you mean also could be like you criticize your her/him behind her/his back to your friends ?

Answer (score 1):

`"Critical of"` means

> Judging severely and finding fault

Check [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/critical)

Here, the speaker can judge his/her partner and find faults when he/she is in a relationship.